# video ```loop``` attribute is not working on FireFox browser

Tags: reactjs, loops

```
<video ref={vidRef} controls={false} autoPlay={true} muted loop={true} onContextMenu={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
     <source src="./img/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

I am trying to play video infinite so i have used loop attribute on video tag but it is not working in fireFox, but it is working in chrome though.
I am using react for this project. So any solution on this?

Answer (score 2):

Write like this:

```
<video src="./img/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" ref={vidRef} autoplay muted loop onContextMenu={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
</video>
```

No need for true or false.